# Guide to obtaining Dread Pirate Ring heirloom

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have all of the pieces of heirloom that can be obtained for a Mage I'm going to level except for the `Dread Pirate Ring` which is linked here: http://www.wowhead.com/item=50255

I don't know of any other heirloom rings available and this one has some nice bonuses. I hear it's quite the pain to get and I'm having difficulty finding good advice for having the best odds of getting it in the shortest amount of time.

Would someone with experience getting this item be able to give some advice? Am I overlooking other heirloom rings that are available so I can avoid doing this one?

I have never fished before. Does my fishing skill need to be at a certain level? Do I need to buy a pole from somewhere prior to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your hearthstone to to Dalaran.  Be in Northrend saturday 14:00.  Fish until you catch a Blacktip Shark, then hearthstone to Dalaran to turn it in.

Btw, I choose Boots of the Bay as reward :)

Comment: Do I need to have fishing to a certain level before then? I've never fished before. Do I need to buy anything?

Comment: It can be fished with any fishing skill (req. 1 skill)  It can be fished at any school of fish in northrend.

Answer (score 1):

The Dalaran fishing contest [no longer takes place](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/7207170), so if you want this ring today, you will need to be the [first](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=8193) or [second](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=32435) person to complete the Stranglethorn fishing tournament.

I've won this tournament twice by:

- Setting hearthstone to Booty Bay, at least 30 minutes *before* the tournament starts
- Going up to the northwest edge of Northern Stranglethorn near the Westfall border
- When the tournament starts, fish southward
- At 40 fish, hearth and turn in the fish

Comment: As of Legion, the Stranglethorn Fishing Extravaganza and all other fishing contests are gone. So, as of right now, there's no way to unlock this ring.

Comment: @Powerlord True. But as Blizzard described it as "temporary" I didn't really see the need to make any updates.